# Why does the jobs tab disappear each day and I have to re-opt in?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I had opted in to the jobs beta.  Been using it but it seems every morning when I come back to it the job tab is gone.  I clear my cache (ctrl f5), I reboot, I clear my entire history, I delete every darn thing from my system except the OS only to see the job tab is once again gone.

I have to go back to the initial meta post by Jason and re "click here" to opt back in to see this tab once again.  Is this by design?

Please note **I am not clearing cookies initially**, I am only doing that after the fact of not finding this tab.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because we made it a Session cookie by accident.

[image]

**UPDATE**: The feature has been released, there's no more opting in or cookie.

Comment: This explains it, can this be changed please to use a regular cookie that doesn't expire until 3k or some random year?