# Jobs misleading tab name on company page

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I really think the [jobs initiative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312452/careers-unificintegration-jobs-on-stack-overflow?cb=1) needs to be redesigned, I can help create expected mock ups if its needed because the workflow just doesn't flow.  Although beta'ed out and people [including myself are logging bug reports](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jobs) I think the flow behind it is still awkward.  I really rely on sites like this but this is just plain old confusing.

Things are not clear and don't flow as expected, I am finding a lot of things that don't seem to make sense, for instance, the tabs between search jobs and search companies is so incredibly similar yet function so differently.  There is a lot of inconsistency between the pages and popups.  For instance, some popups (when applying for a job for instance) don't have a cancel link..while other popups such as asking company X a question do allow you to cancel out.

Links such as "search results" [mysteriously come in and go out with no explanation as to why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312454/searching-by-zip-code-loses-zip-code-after-postback/312640#comment284553_312640)?  There are strange bugs I am finding due to [cookies / caching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312699/why-does-the-jobs-tab-disappear-each-day-and-i-have-to-re-opt-in) on things that shouldn't be [cookied or cached](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312561/what-exactly-is-most-recent-given-days-are-ranked-lower/312579#comment283921_312579).

Then you get into a company page yet a tab is selected stating you are searching for companies:

[image]

Is there any workflow that is being done to redesign this entire user experience because it simply is too confusing. I think it's great that you guys are getting feedback in this mechanism, but I feel this feedback is only to fix or add to what's currently there.  My suggestion is to redesign the entire process.  Yes it seems like a lot of work but it really isn't, it's just a matter of putting things where they belong and making the pages a bit more simpler to understand.

Comment: Aside: you are currently [dominating the asker leaderboard](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/jobs/topusers), which is doubly impressive since Jason's post is featured on like every page of the site... Nice work!

Comment: @Shog9 - never knew such a page existed - just trying to help that's all.  I really care about the careers site because I've been using it to hire people, but I also used it to find opportunities.  I think moving it to SO (from the candidate side) is an awesome idea, but I think there needs to be more direction on how it works.

Comment: That'll come with time and feedback. What's shocking is that some of this behavior has been in place for years and... No one noticed, or said anything. Sunlight is the best disinfectant!

Comment: I used to provide feedback but am always ignored!  We've paid a few times for listings and even then had a lot of issues that I logged but a lot of it went unanswered or never fixed...at the time I gave up.  I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

I know this comes late, but I want to thank you for taking interest in Jobs UX, and also to tell you that we won't right now be implementing any change to the naming of the Jobs & Company sub-tabs.

The main reason: we know navigation here is imperfect and we're investigating a more longterm fix than just renaming the sub tabs.

Thanks again for keeping tabs on us.

Comment: Asked back in january and just got a response holy toledo guys where the heck are ya?

Comment: @JonH see your question's history. It's been bumped quite a few times.

Comment: @Stephen im not sure what you mean

Comment: @JonH http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/312728/revisions